# Udev rule (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, udev, tty

I have a device that is required to bind to /dev/ttyACM0 specifically, so I created a udev rule to ensure that happens. Unfortunately I am seeing a condition in which the device disconnects and reconnects and causes the device to not re-bind to ACM0 again because the system is likely showing something already bound. My question is as follows: Is there something I can do to force an unbind on /dev/ttyACM0 as part of the rule before the attempt to bind? This way it serves 2 purposes, it bumps any device that may have bound to ACM0 and ensures that this condition of losing power doesn't effect the device from rebinding. The rule I created is as follows:

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0102", SYMLINK="ttyACM0Device"
```

Comment: It looks like I found a resolution (potentially). I added the RUN+ option at the end of the udev rule and pointed it toward a bash script with the following:
rm /dev/ttyACM*;
mknod /dev/ttyACM0 c xxx x;
chgrp dialout /dev/ttyACM0;

It may not be the cleanest way to do this, but it appears to be effective. I will update when I run the application test to call to this device and see if I get any errors. I should have prefaced my question with the clarification that this is extremely unfamiliar territory for me

Comment: Tested the application and it has no issues connecting. I even ran the script a few times during the process and it gave no errors. This works as expected